# Servidor local para integrar aplicações web com o sistema operacional

Tags: aplicação-web, electron, app-hibrido

Já existe algum framework/lib que atua como uma ponte,
entre os recursos do sistema operacional e a aplicação web?

Não quero usar Electron (e outros alternativas parecidas),
mas gostaria de aproveitar boa parte da interface da minha aplicação web,
tanto na web como no desktop.

Tipo um Cordova/Capacitor para desktop, mas em forma de uma servidor web,
que forneça recursos do sistema operacional, como sistema de arquivos, apis, etc.

Sei que posso fazer isso, mas se tiver algo pronto seria muito melhor.

Obviamente entendo que o usuário terá que instalar este servidor, para a aplicação web,
poder acessar os recursos locais que uma página web não pode.

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133544/discussion-on-question-by-junior-bnusc-servidor-local-para-integrar-aplicacoes-w)